# Django delete function getting error (Field id expected a number but got)

Tags: jquery, django, django-views

I have create a delete function on Django when i try to delete a post using jQuery I am getting this error `Field` 'id' expected a number but got `\n \n   \n` I also add try to assign id over the pk but I am getting the same error can anybody tell me how can I use this function using jQuery

```py
def ArticleDelete(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        pk = request.POST.get('pk')
        article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=pk)
        messages.success(request, 'The story was deleted successfully!')
        article.delete()
        return JsonResponse({"success": True}, status=200)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({"success": False}, status=400)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('delete/', views.ArticleDelete, name='delete'),
}
```

index.js

```js
$('.delete').click(function () {
        var this_html = $(this);
        var pk = this_html.parent().parent().children().first().text();

        $.ajax({
            url: '{% url "del" %}',
            type: 'POST',
            headers: { "X-CSRFToken": '{{csrf_token}}' },
            data: { pk: pk },
            success: function () {
                this_html.parent().parent().remove();
            }
        });
    })
```

Comment: the problem seems from ```var pk``` , show your template file. also, ```console.log(pk)``` may help you debug.

Answer (score 1):

Add something to print out the value of pk from your request.POST (to make sure it is what you think)

```
pk = request.POST.get('pk')
print('pk from POST = ', pk)
```

You could also try forcing pk to a known value in your ArticleDelete function to isolate whether the problem is coming from iffy data in the request.POST or something else within the ArticleDelete function

Oh wait - it looks like you've got a type mismatch now that I look again. Try casting your pk from the POST to an int, so...

```
if request.method == "POST":
    pk = int(request.POST.get('pk'))  # Make it an int before passing to query
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=pk)
    ...
```

Right now it's being returned as a string, which the database doesn't seem to like - it looks like it wants an integer value instead